# Does watching a video ad in a playlist get the creator any money?

Tags: youtube, youtube-playlist

If I watch a YouTube video in a playlist, it doesn't count as a view. I want to know if watching ads on playlist videos gets the creator any money. Does watching the full ad get them more money than skipping the ad?

Answer (score 2):

> If I watch a YouTube video in a playlist, it doesn't count as a view.

It does, the view counter just doesn't update immediately.

> I want to know if watching ads on playlist videos gets the creator any money.

The video's creator gets all the money, not the playlist creator.

> Does watching the full ad get them more money than skipping the ad?

Creators get only money if you either click on the ad or watch it at least 30s, or fully if the ad is shorter. If you skip it, they don't get anything.

That said: Don't click on ads all the time just to support the creator. This is considered invalid click activity by AdSense and not counted at all; the creator may even get punished for it.

Answer (score -1):

Money is made through monetization of ad revenue. So the viewer must click on the ad for money to be earned. Which is referred to as CPC "Cost per Click"